# As a Syrian passport holder, how good are my chances in getting a UK residency, and what can I do to improve them?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit

I'm a Syrian passport holder and a resident in Turkey. I was offered a job in the UK and I want to move there. My question is how good are my chances considering the current situation in Syria? And what can I do to improve them?

Note the fact that [acceptance rate dropped from ~70% to ~40% in the last 3 years](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/refugee-crisis-thousands-of-syrians-have-uk-visa-requests-rejected-by-home-office-10492206.html).

Some background: I'm a Software Engineer with ~4 years of experience, a B.Sc. holder from a British university (studied remotely), and I've never been to the UK or any EEA country before; I'm 23, and my financial situation is considerably good. I'll be applying for a Tier 2 (General) visa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out not to be so bad. I was accepted.

You just need to show that you have:

- a clean history
- a sustainable job
- sufficient funds (so that they know they won't be spending money on you next year.)